# What are the rules to mark a question as too broad?

Tags: discussion, needs-more-focus

I'd really like to understand the concept of questions considered being as "too broad". For instance, what makes a moderator to flag one question as too broad?

I see a lot of good questions flagged as too broad over and over. The term "broadness" in the context of SO is extremely diffuse. Think about it, you can flag the 100% of existing questions in the site as too broad applying a perfect logic.

Let's take a look to a random popular [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type), that question includes sentences like "which is correct, or best?", is not that too broad? Well... if you define a strict set of rules to clarify what "broadness" means maybe is not... otherwise I could argue than that question is too broad because I could perfectly write few books to answer "properly".

So, again, what are the considered points to flag a question as too broad? A question admiting lengthy answers? well... 100% of questions from the site would admit book length answers, so that must not be... Being the question too subjective? Under which point of view? the guy who asked? an experienced coder? mostly of the people trying to answer it? Only moderators? People with enough reputation? That also must not be...

IMHO, marking a question as too broad mostly of the time is applied really badly by moderators, I see ruining good questions mostly of the time. If we consider as a "good" questions something which could provide good answers and bringing some knowledge/benefits to people. Why a question which could generate (possibly) a lot of good content can be ruined?

The reason why I've opened this topic is because of one recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42722149/how-to-refactor-functions) of mine being marked as "too broad". I guess it depends from the point of view or the logic used to determine "broadness"

Summing up, unless there is a strict set of rules to consider a "broad" question this term is extremely diffuse. It seems to me like a perfect excuse to break SO more and more and annoy people over and over.

IMHO, subjective criterions given to moderators as tools to "moderate" don't bring any benefit at all... Of course, SO is not my baby at the end of the day so I can just complain or pointing out facts which spoil even more the site.

For instance, regarding to my question flagged as "too broad"... few answers were starting to emerge before being put "on hold", maybe they weren't exactly the main question, so what? Anything wrong with that? Even so, they were adding valuable facts which could be useful to people interested on the subject and links to some good interesting books.

So yeah, summing up (I'll try not being too broad here), what's the benefit of this (IMHO unuseful) rule of "broadness"? and... how do moderators consider when a question is "too broad"?

PS: Yeah, i've read the guidelines of SO about how-to-ask and similars

Comment: You can't really use a post from 8 years ago as an example.  The site has evolved over time and what was okay/allowed in 2009 is not the same as today.  The reason a lot of them are not closed is we cannot keep up with the flood of new stuff to close so we really have no time to go close old off topic stuff if it is not hurting anything.

Comment: @NathanOliver I've put that example... but bring me some counterexample and I can prove you easily that particular question can be too broad as well

Comment: `maybe they weren't exactly the main question, so what? Anything wrong with that?` Yes, yes there is.  SO is designed to be a question and answer site where a question is shown along with answers to that question.  "Answers" that don't answer the question are, thus, a problem.

Comment: I'm saying that old question should be closed.  It hasn't though because when it was posted it was okay to post things like that and no one has gone back and closed it.

Comment: @NathanOliver The example question isn't subjective or broad.  It provides a list of values and ask which of them are correct according to the spec.  There's a single, short, correct answer.  (One of the options listed happens to be the one listed in the spec as correct.)

Comment: @Servy Yeah, and that's your opinion about being not too broad, "yours and maybe others". My opinion is that particular question to be answered properly needs length books answer. At the moment your afirming categorically "There's a single, short, correct answer" you're proving my point

Comment: Haha, it's funny, and now I've brought this topic people started to downvote my question from Stackoverflow... and before it was being upvoted, seriously... this site is extremely broken :D

Comment: @BPL How does it require a book length answer to list the proper MIME type for JSON?  The spec says what the correct text is for that MIME type.  That's all that you need to provide to provide a correct answer, and it's quite succinct.  This is seen in the top answers themselves, all of which manage to provide answers in much less length than a book, and are complete correct answers to the question.

Comment: @BPL Before you linked the question it had *one* vote, not multiple upvotes.  You shined a bright spotlight on your question, and specifically asked a bunch of quality-minded people to evaluate the quality of your question.  The result of that is some of those people *are* going to provide their opinion on the quality of the post.

Comment: @BPL, by pointing people to your question here, you are exposing the post to the "meta-effect". Since it was already established that the community thought your question should be closed for being "too broad", it's not a big surprise you are getting downvotes with the additional exposure.

Comment: @Servy Well, let's focus on that particular question, you can read the sentence "But which is correct, or best?" , in what sense is not that too broad? Is it well defined the meaning of correct or best? It's implicit... therefore too broad. I mean, if you are too picky you can elaborate about all question can become too broad. Ok, let me ask you here (out of curiosity)... what's your particular definition of "broadness" then?

Comment: @BPL It's not too broad because there's a specification for what type should be provided, and that specification objectively and unambiguously states what should be used.  That's all there is.  The "correct" type is the type that the specifications state should be used.  If there weren't a spec that specifically stated what the correct type is, then perhaps the problem would be too subjective, but that's simply not the case here.  You can see a definition of "Too Broad" in the banner under your question.

Comment: @yivi Interesting to know about the "meta-effect"... People sometimes are like sheeps which follow the flow... They tend to follow trends, I'd put my finger that if my "broad" question wouldn't have put on hold or exposed to this meta-effect and upvoted few times, that trend would have been followed.

Comment: meta effect is not about people being like sheep at all. It just means you are giving additional exposure to a post. It just accelerates natural trends for votes/closures/etc. That your post had one positive vote before being linked here doesn't mean much on its own.

Comment: @BPL That claim is pretty demonstrably false.  If the people were "sheep" and were only going to follow the flow, then they would have upvoted the question, considering, as you said, the question was upvoted.  That they *didn't* follow the trend of votes on the question, and did the opposite, they pretty clearly *weren't* doing that, and disagreed with the previous voter as to the quality of the question.  If you just dismiss the people that are pointing out problems with your question as not actually evaluating it, then you won't be able to fix it.

Comment: @yivi Well, when somebody (moderator) has flagged a question is not a "natural" trend anymore, it's manipulated the trend. That's why I've pointed out in my question that if a tool which can't be defined properly as in this case, the term "broadness". You're giving people (mods) tools to alter the flow of questions and annoying people around... In any case, as I've said, not my site not my rules... If everybody likes the way it is, I guess it's fine

Comment: @Servy You need to consider always external forces, otherwise the experiment becomes invalidated.

Comment: Question was closed because people raised flags to close, and people voted on those flags. So it's as "natural" as it gets. There are no "external" forces.

Comment: @BPL So then you agree that your own assertion was invalidated.  Okay then.

Comment: @Servy Let me try to simplify here. a) Your site your rules, fair enough b) The concept of broadness is objectively diffuse c) My question has been spoiled, nobody will benefit from that  d) I've opened this post in order to understand the underlying rules governing SO and I don't  e) A lot of people out there gets annoyed with SO very often, so there must be a reason . Anyway, not saying SO is a bad site, sometimes is pretty awesome... But the fact of not being able to bring interesting generic questions can be really annoying for people not interested on just particular cases like me.

Comment: @yivi Thanks, that's a proactive comment providing real value :)

Comment: The comment is added automatically when someone (me, in this case), raises the "duplicate" flag.

Comment: @BPL It's not *other people's* fault that your question is too broad and was closed as a result.  It's *your* fault for asking a problematic question.  If you want to fix it so that it's *not* too broad, perhaps you can salvage it.  It's not other people's fault for pointing out that your question is bad though; they weren't the ones that bad it bad.  Many people get annoyed with SO because they want to provide low quality or off topic content, and SO tries to stop them.  Such people don't like it when that happens.

Comment: @BPL I'm currently not sure whether you're asking why SO needs a "too broad" close reason or what the definition is for too broad on SO (which you can read up in the flag menu) or whether you're asking why your particular question fits into that definition.

Comment: @Servy Well, I won't judge the quality of my question in terms of the language because probably is a really bad one (my english is quite creepy), fair enough. On the other hand, even if a lot of people under their criterions consider the question low quality, that's fine with me... But definitely their criterion is quite different to mine, I've been coding for a lot of years and the fact of learning more about refactoring properly functions is a really good question. And btw, the reason why I don't like it is because the fact I've lost time asking some interesting stuff which has been ruined

Comment: Then it's probably best to learn what works here and what doesn't. I frequently have programming related questions that I *really really* want answered - but I know they wouldn't work on Stack Overflow because it's not a place for every question, so I don't ask them there. What I do instead is find other places to ask the question (or try to find out myself.)

Comment: @Pekka웃 I guess that's a good advice, I think I'll take it! It's like saying "this site is what it is, it won't change... so, adapt yourself to it and get the best from it... or don't use it :)" .

Comment: @BPL yup, that's pretty much what I mean. The site *does* change, but the process is slow and very hard for single voices to influence if the majority has different ideas, like in any other massive democratic (or sort-of-democratic) group. And it's still looking like it's changing towards *more* specificity and narrowness in focus, not less...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Summing up, unless there is a strict set of rules to consider a "broad" question this term is extremely diffuse.

One very good indicator for a "too broad" question is that there could be a huge (theoretically endless) number of good possible answers to it, and/or that a good answer would likely be the size of a long blog post or a book. "How to refactor functions" is that kind of question.

Another indicator is questions that actually contain *a lot* of questions. You acknowledge yourself that that's the case in your example: `Many interrogants come to my mind`.

> what's the benefit of this (IMHO unuseful) rule of "broadness"?

The benefit is creating (very imperfectly) a repository of technical questions and answers that are useful to future readers because, generally, they do not contain meandering discussions, but are pairs of questions *and specific answers to that question* - the main reason why Stack Overflow was created.

That's not to say that long, meandering discussions about programming topics are *bad*. They're totally fair, educative, and useful, just as your example question potentially is.

They just don't have a place *on this specific web site.*

Comment: Alright... but think about it... theorically you can provide endless answers of any size to almost any question, can't you? This is the key point I don't really understand. I mean, when expanding maths you start from a really strict set of rules and everything makes sense. With the concept of broadness there isn't a "logical" definition which makes sense to me, that's why I don't understand.

Comment: @BPL think about it from the other side: if it's impossible to provide a good short answer, then you likely have a too broad question. "How to refactor functions?" seems like exactly that kind of question. You could easily write a book or blog post answering it. That's the kind of thing that doesn't work on Stack Overflow (any more).

Comment: Mmmm, interesting point of view...